# Multiple while <option> update with query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to achieve an update query for multiple `<options>` from a while loop. I am using this feature to assign position id's for images so that i can place them on various positions in the website. I have it working for a single image, but that means I have to update each image manually.

In my current situation i am running the form inside a while loop. Then the submit button posts the data to a process file and it saves. That works. But only for each image individually.

**I want to be able to update all image positions with a single submit button.**

In my current code I think the problem is that i run the form inside a while loop. Using data from multiple forms in a single query is not possible if i am right. Now i'm writing this request for help I am noticing it is more of a business logic error- i am trying to wrap my head around it to get it to work.

Lets get to the situation/code:

---

It currently works like this:

**option > button**

**option > button**

Each update button directs to a file 'photoPositions.php' with an article id and executes the insert query.

I want this situation:

**option**

**option**

**update button**

Resulting in: update all images with a single click.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdEWu.png)

---

The Insertquery on photoPositions.php looks like this:

```
$insertQuery = ("UPDATE images SET posId = '".$_POST['posid']."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['imgid']."'");
    mysql_query($insertQuery) or die(mysql_error());
```

(i know `mysql_` is depcrecated, i'll try to work on that later)

My current edit article code looks like this:

```
<?php 
echo 'Images:<br>';
echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="3">'; 
$get_photo = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE artId = ".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY posId ASC";
$result = mysql_query($get_photo) or die(mysql_error());    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<td align="left">
        <a href="../photos/'.$row['name'].'" target="_blank">
        <img src="../photos/'.$row['name'].'" width=200>
        </a>';
?>
        <form name="imagePosition" method="post" action="photoPositions.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="imgid" id="imgid" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
        <select name="posid" id="posid">
<?php 
        echo '<option value="1"';
            if($row['posId'] == 1)
            {
                echo ' selected';
            }
        echo '>Article</option>';

        echo '<option value="2"';
            if($row['posId'] == 2)
            {
                echo ' selected';
            }
        echo '>Sidebar</option>';

        echo '<option value="4"';
            if($row['posId'] == 4)
            {
                echo ' selected';
            }
        echo '>Offline</option>';
?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="POSITION CHANGE" value="POSITION CHANGE">
        </form>
<?php
    }
echo '</table>' . "\r\n"; 
?>
```

The image positions is part of a larger edit screen with another form. I'm trying to integrate the photopositions update into 1 update process for the whole edit article- instead of doing each image manually..

Do i have to output the posid data for all imgid data into an array and process that data into a query? Of course i have to fix the form in a while issue too i assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is change the `<select name="posid">` to an array with the `$row['id']` as the key `<select name="posid[$row['id']]">`

```
<?php 
echo 'Images:<br>';

//move form tag to outside of table
echo '<form name="imagePosition" method="post" action="photoPositions.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">';

echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="3">'; 
$get_photo = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE artId = ".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY posId ASC";
$result = mysql_query($get_photo) or die(mysql_error());    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<td align="left">
        <a href="../photos/'.$row['name'].'" target="_blank">
        <img src="../photos/'.$row['name'].'" width=200>
        </a>';
?>
        <select name="posid[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" id="posid<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<?php 
        echo '<option value="1"';
            if($row['posId'] == 1)
            {
                echo ' selected';
            }
        echo '>Article</option>';

        echo '<option value="2"';
            if($row['posId'] == 2)
            {
                echo ' selected';
            }
        echo '>Sidebar</option>';

        echo '<option value="4"';
            if($row['posId'] == 4)
            {
                echo ' selected';
            }
        echo '>Offline</option>';
?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="POSITION CHANGE" value="POSITION CHANGE">
<?php
    }
echo '</table></form>' . "\r\n"; 
?>
```

then in your `photoPositions.php` you can do a foreach loop

```
foreach($_POST['posid'] as $key => $value){
      $insertQuery = ("UPDATE images SET posId = '".$value."' WHERE id = '".$key."'");
      mysql_query($insertQuery) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, it works. I spend hours on this. 
I'll definitely try to understand my errors and your solution. I had a feeling a foreach would do the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Always glad to help. Sometimes it takes an outside eye to help get the creative thinking going again.